# How to convert string "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" to DateTime format in Cosmos DB query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to convert string "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" to DateTime format in Cosmos DB query.
E.g.: Date is stored as "8/19/2023 4:44:55 PM" and it needs to converted into standard date to apply date operations (e.g. yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.0000000Z'.
Also, query should append 0 in case of single digit date/month.
And I cannot use UDF and has to be done via Query.

Comment: Please edit your question to show exact data that you have and what you're trying to store, along with what you tried. Note that there are several helper functions built-in, such as `DateTimeFromParts()`. Aside from all that, you should consider storing ISO date/time format strings, rather than other formats, as a standard approach (knowing that Cosmos DB doesn't have a built-in datetime type)

Answer (score 0):

By using this User-Define Function (UDF), you can convert the string "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" to DateTime format and perform date operations in your Cosmos DB queries.

Create a UDF in your Cosmos DB account using the Azure Portal or Azure CLI.
Example of the code:

```
// JavaScript UDF to convert string to DateTime format
function convertStringToDateTime(dateString) {
    var parts = dateString.split(/[\s/:]+/);
    var year = parseInt(parts[2]);
    var month = parseInt(parts[0]) - 1; // months are 0-based in JavaScript Date object
    var day = parseInt(parts[1]);
    var hour = parseInt(parts[3]);
    var minute = parseInt(parts[4]);
    var second = parseInt(parts[5]);

    if (parts[6] === "PM" && hour < 12) {
        hour += 12;
    }

    return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
}
```

The example above UDF written in JavaScript, you can save it in your Cosmos DB account for reusability.

With the example below you can use UDF in your Cosmos DB queries:

```
SELECT c.id, udf.convertStringToDateTime(c.dateString) AS convertedDateTime
FROM c
```

Replace c.dateString with the path to the string field containing the date in your documents.

Comment: The OP should really edit their question to show specifics, including what they tried. Also, there are built-in functions such as `DateTimeFromParts()` that might meet their needs. But until they show work of their own, it's a good idea to not-post custom implementations.

Comment: NOTED. Good advice, a generic question require a generic answer.

Comment: More like, an incomplete question should get feedback on how to improve it, without needing to answer.

Comment: Absolutely! But in other way, no foolish questions. Thanks @David Makogon for the experience.